# How to render jade file using nodejs, expressjs

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I created a project using express tool "express -s",
By default it assign jade as default views templating system.

I have also create a file index.html and i converted it using html2jade tool, the problem is when i try to access index.jade file using this function :

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
     console.log('welcome admin');
     res.render('admin/app/index', {  }); 
}
```

i got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at Object.Function (unknown source)
```

Please can someone explain what's wrong :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you use ejs, because you can use html: http://embeddedjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
That problem seems to be some formatting issue. you can use ejs instead. add the following to your app.js:
// map .renderFile to ".html" files
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// make ".html" the default
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//Then you can use below code to render html files and code in ejs:
res.render('index.html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're not sending any data to the index file. I would try something like this..

```
    exports.index = function(req, res){
      console.log('welcome admin');
      res.render('index', { output: 'Welcome Admin' }); 
    }
```

And then in your app.js file you want to have

```
    app.get('/', routes.index);
```

and then in your index.jade file should have the tag for output key.so that whatever the value is given to output key is printed in the template.

Answer (score 0):

That error typically means that there's a problem with the Jade syntax in your template so I would double check that - the output to the terminal should contain more detailed information about where the parsing error occurred.

Also, if you don't already have it configured, I would recommend adding the following to turn on Connect's error handler:

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});
```